# Eclipse 4.x (Mars) Multipage Form

Tags: java, eclipse, forms, eclipse-rcp, e4

Short version:

How do I make use of multi-page Eclipse Forms in an Eclipse RCP 4.X Application (Mars 4.5.0) ?

Long version:

In trying to learn how multi-page forms work in an Eclipse RCP, I am finding that the documentation on this topic and the available tutorials are still in 3.x

Official documentation link
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fforms_editors.htm

A good tutorial link
https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html

The eclipse.org tutorial was very good but breaks down when you get to multi-page forms, due to the differences between 3.X and 4.X. I was unable to locate an up-to-date tutorial or information on this.

I just need a trivial example of a 4.X part that is able to display a basic multi-page form and I can work from there. Anyone got the goods?

Comment: Are you asking about a pure 'e4' style RCP or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: I am looking for a pure e4 option, as the rest of my application is being developed that way. In fact I have not learned the 3.X style as yet. If the two can coexist and there is no other option, and it would continue to be supported in the future, then compatibility mode could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for this in an e4 application. You will have to craft the code for this yourself.

The basic multiple tab editor is just based on a `CTabFolder` control. The Form editor is based on this but is considerably more complex.

If you want to make use of the existing Eclipse editor support and the workspace file system (`IFile` and the like) then you need to use a 3.x compatibility RCP. There is some support in this for e4 style parts to be included.

Since 100s of Eclipse plugins are coded using the 3.x style there is no chance of support for this being dropped in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thanks for the info!